# Compass compile still generates CSS when failed

Tags: sass, compass-sass

Is it possible that if compass compile fails (for example with `undefined variable`)

it would just shut down and cancel it's compilation instead of still writing out to the end file

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Wouldn't it be simpler to just, you know, fix the error to begin with?

Comment: If you watch instead of manually compiling, seems like the errors stop .css file generation.

Comment: Thanks Niloct! You make your comment as an answer